# Libgdx tiles get overlapped on render

Tags: 2d, libgdx, textures, tilemap, maps

I'm trying to create a Tilemap with 64x64 textures which follows this configuration.

```
private int[][] intMat = {
         {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
        ,{1, 0, 0, 0, 1}
        ,{1, 0, 0, 0, 1}
        ,{1, 0, 0, 0, 1}
        ,{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
};
```

from a given array, where `1->forest` and `0 -> plain`, I try to place them together, hopefully creating a map.

```
    @Override
public void create () {
    textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas("testPack.atlas");
    tileMap = new TileMap(5, 5);


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            Tile tile;
            if (intMat[i][j] == 1) {
                tile = new Tile(i, "scrub_forest", new TextureRegion(textureAtlas.findRegion("1scrub_forest")));
            } else {
                tile = new Tile(i, "plain", new Texture("plains.png"));
            }
            tileMap.setTile(tile, i , j);
        }
    }
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}
```

The `tileMap` is loaded with tiles using the `intMat`configuration.

```
    @Override
public void render () {
    ScreenUtils.clear(50, 50, 50, 1);

    System.out.println("[INFO] Render start");
    batch.begin();
    //TODO: Iterator perhaps?
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            batch.draw(tileMap.getTiles()[i][j].getTexture(), i*TEXTURE_SIZE, j*TEXTURE_SIZE);
            System.out.println("i*TEXTURE_SIZE: " + i*TEXTURE_SIZE + " - " + j*TEXTURE_SIZE);
        }
    }
    batch.end();
    System.out.println("[INFO] Render off");
}
```

Then on render I space them out using `TEXTURE_SIZE`

**What I expected to obtain**

A configuration which follows the initial matrix setup. Instead, I got this result:

[image]

I though I was "drawing" the textures with there coordinates:

```
(0,0) (0,64), (0, 128)...
(64, 0), (64, 64), (64, 128)...
```